# Thomas Algorithm for Tridiagonal System

Tags: matrices, numerical-methods, numerical-linear-algebra, matrix-equations, gaussian-elimination

A professor gave us an assignment to solve a Tridiagonal system using Thomas Algorithm. Here is the exercise:

[image]

I am lost as to what to do with that $(0.2\pi)^2$ and do I just calculate the $\sin(0.2\pi)$ to assign it as the value for equation 1?

I'm used to solving exercises like this one with Thomas Algorithm:
[image]

Can someone guide me in the right direction as to how to solve this? Maybe it's very simple and I am overthinking the whole $(0.2\pi)^2$ thing.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Welcome to MSE! [Here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) is a small guide on how to typeset your math.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you are overthinking the whole $\pi^2/25$ thing.  Just multiply each of the components of the vector on the right by that factor; you are solving
$$
M \vec{u} = \left(
\begin{array}{c} 
\frac{\pi^2}{25}\sin(\pi/5) \\
\frac{\pi^2}{25}\sin(2\pi/5) \\
\frac{\pi^2}{25}\sin(3\pi/5) \\
\frac{\pi^2}{25}\sin(4\pi/5) 
\end{array}\right)
$$